# How to split a string into list and combine two known token into one in python?

Tags: python, regex, split, tokenize

For a given string like:

`"Today is a bright sunny day in New York"`

I want to make my list to be:

`['Today','is','a','bright','sunny','day','in','New York']`

Another example:

`"This is a hello world program"`

The list be: 
`['This', 'is', 'a', 'hello world', 'program']`

For every given string S, we have the entities E which needs to be kept together. The first example had entity E to be "New", "York" and the second example had entity to be "hello","world".

I have tried to get it done via regex but I am unsuccessful in splitting by spaces and merging two entities.

Example:

`regex = "(navy blue)|[a-zA-Z0-9]*"
 match = re.findall(regex, "the sky looks navy blue.",re.IGNORECASE)
 print match`

Output:
`['', '', '', '', '', '', 'navy blue', '', '']`

Comment: Do you know the entities in advance? i.e. Do you have list of entities in advance like ['New York', 'hello world'].

Comment: `tried to get it done via regex` please add those efforts to question.. the downvotes are probably because you didn't add code.. also, a suggestion to use `{}` code block for formatting samples instead of quotes

Comment: @Sundeep Thanks for the advice. I have made the relevant changes.

Comment: Do you want to find only name entity from a string ?

Comment: @AbdullahAhmedGhaznavi No, the problem is not of named entity recognition.

Comment: @amogh Mishra: Yeah find name entity from a string is not a difficult task. but your scenario is interesting. let me check it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `re.findall` instead of `split` and supply the entity in alternation before the character class that represents string to extract

```
>>> s = "Today is a bright sunny day in New York"
>>> re.findall(r'New York|\w+', s)
['Today', 'is', 'a', 'bright', 'sunny', 'day', 'in', 'New York']

>>> s = "This is a hello world program"
>>> re.findall(r'hello world|\w+', s)
['This', 'is', 'a', 'hello world', 'program']
```

change `\w` to appropriate character class, for ex: `[a-zA-Z]`

For the additional sample added to question

```
>>> regex = r"navy blue|[a-z\d]+"
>>> re.findall(regex, "the sky looks navy blue.", re.IGNORECASE)
['the', 'sky', 'looks', 'navy blue']
```

- Use `r` strings to construct regex patterns as a good practice
- grouping not needed here
- use `+` instead of `*` so that at least one character has to be matched
- since `re.IGNORECASE` is specified, either `a-z` or `A-Z` is enough in character class. can also use `re.I` as short-cut
- `\d` is short-cut for `[0-9]`

Comment: Thanks! Perfect solution!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
text = "Today is a bright sunny day in New York"
new_list = list(map(str, text.split(" ")))
```

This should give you the following output `['Today', 'is', 'a', 'bright', 'sunny', 'day', 'in', 'New', 'York']`

Same for the next string:

```
hello = "This is a hello world program."
yet_another_list = list(map(str, hello.split(" ")))
```

Gives you `['This', 'is', 'a', 'hello', 'world', 'program.']`

Comment: I think he is asking to keep New York together.

Comment: Thanks but I want 'New York' to be one single token, not in different index. The one you mentioned is equivalent to str.split().

Comment: Oh, I see. Do you know in advance which elements of a given string should be kept together? @AmoghMishra

Comment: @Baduker Yes, I know. For every sentence/string, I know which tokens needs to be merged.

Answer (score 1):

```
"this is hello word program".split(' ')
```

the split will automatically make a list. you can you split using any string or word or characters.