# Combine List of Known Token Pairs together

Tags: python, nlp, token, tokenize

I have a list of potentially many token pairs I want to keep together when tokenizing some text. For Simplicity, say I have the token pairs;

```
pairs = ['New York', San Francisco, 'Washington DC']
text = 'this is some text with cities New York, San Franciso, and Washington DC'
```

The goal is to tokenize a sentence such that these pairs are kept together

```
tokenized_text
>>>> ['this', 'is', 'some', 'text', 'with', 'cities', 'New York', 'San Franciso', 'and', 'Washington DC']
```

I know re.findall can help achieve this for a specific token pair (see [How to split a string into list and combine two known token into one in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49109150/how-to-split-a-string-into-list-and-combine-two-known-token-into-one-in-python)), but what if I have many?

**EDIT**

Given the answer below, this solution works:

```
pairs = ['New York', San Francisco, 'Washington DC']
text = 'This is some text with cities New York, San Franciso, and Washington DC'
pattern = '|'.join(word for word in pairs) 
re.findall(f'{pattern}|\w+', text)
```